# Simple question about Integral from 0 to f(x) instead of x

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{f(x)} g'(t) \, \mathrm{d}t$$

Can someone explain why this equals $g(f(x))-g(f(0))$? I'm really confused since the derivative is different and the fundamental theorem of calculus only supports integral from $0$ to $x$.
Thanks after a little bit of thinking and rechecking the fundamental theorem of calculus, i got it in my head its 3 am here so i'm a bit dizzy, everything is clear now , thanks guys.

Comment: It does not matter, the limits are treated as constant during the integration. Also, that should be $g(f(x))-g(0)$ (or otherwise the lower limit should be $f(0)$)

Comment: The definition of the integral from $a$ to $b$ of $f'(x)$ is $f(b)-f(a)$.  The result you show is a simple substitution matching this definition.

Comment: if the limits are treated as constants during the integration , then why the derivative of $$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{f(x)} g'(t) \, \mathrm{d}t$$ isn't g'(x)? if we put f(x)=n , then we get F(n) ?I know it must be treated as fog composite of two functions when deriving but why this logic yields a wrong answer

Comment: That's an entirely different operation (it is differentiating w.r.t. one of the limits, rather than performing the integration). I don't understand your second sentence.

Comment: Were you asked for the derivative?  The derivative of $g(f(x))-g(f(0))$ with respect to $x$ is ${d(g(f(x))) \over dx} = f'(x)g'(f(x))$.

Answer (score 3):

$$\int_a^bg'(x)dx=g(b)-g(a)$$
$$\int_{\text{lion}}^{\text{elephant}}g'(x)dx=g(\text{elephant})-g(\text{lion})$$
$$\int_{\text{sun}}^{\text{moon}}g'(x)dx=g(\text{moon})-g(\text{sun})$$
$$\int_0^{f(x)}g'(x)dx=g(f(x))-g(0)$$

Answer (score 1):

The integral of a derivative f'(a) is clearly the function f(a). Thus the answer to the integral would be g(t), t1 = 0 and t2 = f(x).